# Intel XDK cordova file api 1.3.3 file not found

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, intel-xdk

Simply the issue im calling the file system as :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'/www/icons', function(dirEntry){example=dirEntry}, onError);
```

and im 100% sure the directory exists in my source folders before building application , but after building application i can see that www/index.html exists but no other folders are found , only when i check particular files like www/img/example.svg cause im sure this will be included as they appear in application preview , and are included in css files , the problem is that i get the following error :

```
Error occurred during request to file system pointer. Error code is: 1
```

After lot of searching it appears to be that it is not only who has this issue check this **[post](http://qnimate.com/working-with-file-system-using-intel-xdk/)**

a temporary solution is to fall back to old API ver 0.2.5 which works well without this bug , but just in case anyone knows what is going wrong , please provide a clear answer .

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in 1.3.3 being resolved , for further details check **[this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/commit/356d334382fe7f827b2635e0c3f819453f746bab)** , and **[this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/pull/84)** , just in case anyone is searching for a solution sounds that version 1.3.4 will solve this.